Переадресация приложения Flask с http на https
Не могу настроить передресацию моего приложения на https. К примеру, домен сайта domain.ru.
Проблема следующая:
Сайт открывается по адесу https://domain.ru, но недоступен с протоколом http, по http://domain.ru соответственно.
Когда пользователь вводит в адресную строку браузера domain.ru, должно происходить перенаправление с порта 80 на 443.
Запуск приложения на Flask происходит следующим образом:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False, host='domain.ru', port='443', ssl_context=context)

При запуске приложения отображается следующее:
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on https://domain.ru:443

Также, в приложении присутствует функция ниже и используется библиотека SSLify.
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if not request.is_secure:
        url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://', 1)
        return redirect(url)

Подскажите пж-та, как решить проблему с переадресацией сайта с http на https?
Если изменить порт на 80, при запуске приложения, адрес будет  https://domain.ru:80, что также не позволяет сайту открываться при вводе одного домена.

Во-первых, НЕЛЬЗЯ использовать app.run для запуска сайта на проде, он предназначен только для разработки. Во-вторых, на проде обычно ставят nginx, который и обслужит все порты и сделает все перенаправления
